# Rails | performance when I pass an object to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, web, partial-views, activeresource

I know it's probably not such a big issue, but I have a question that interests me:
In rails (and in a web application in general), lets say I have an object that includes the following properties: `TinyMember(name: string, id: integer)`.

1. I use the given id to fetch another larger object from a web-service: `@member = MyService::Member.find(id)`.
2. In my view, I have to pass the member object to 2 different partials:

   `= render partial: "p1", member: @member`

   `= render partial: "p2", member: @member`

I know that the TinyMember object has enough information for the second partial (p2), my question is if I would improve the performance somehow if I "send" only the lighter TinyMember to this partial, like this:

`= render partial: "p2", member: @tiny_member`